# While Creating the new meteor getting error

Tags: meteor

While creating the new meteor project getting the below error, updated the proxy variables also.

```
D:\meteor>meteor create simple-todos
=> Errors while creating your project

While downloading blaze@2.3.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading blaze-html-templates@1.1.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading blaze-tools@1.0.10...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading caching-html-compiler@1.1.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading html-tools@1.0.11...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading htmljs@1.0.11...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading spacebars@1.0.15...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading spacebars-compiler@1.1.3...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading templating@1.3.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading templating-compiler@1.3.3...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading templating-runtime@1.3.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading templating-tools@1.1.2...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443

While downloading ui@1.0.13...: error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND warehouse.meteor.com warehouse.meteor.com:443
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am behind the proxy.